# conda: Missing dependencies when starting spyder (cahe issues?)

Tags: python, conda, spyder

I (tried to) install spyder5 (for developing python programs) via anaconda.
When starting spyder, I get 2 dependencies failures:

```
You have missing dependencies!
#Mandatory:
jedi =0.17.2:0.18.0 (NOK)
parso =0.7.0:0.8.2 (NOK)
```

However,

```
conda list
```

answers with:

```
...
jedi                      0.17.2           py38h06a4308_1
...
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
...
```

Which seems to indicate that the correct versions are installed on my conda environment.
"Googling" a bit lead me to [this post](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12040), where @ccordoba12 states that this problem can be solved by removing:
C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python

That is of course assuming windows. I could not try since I am running on linux

So my question is:

1. what is the problem (!)?
2. If python (...) caches packages as this seems to indicate, doesn't it defeat the objective of conda?
3. Assuming this caching is really the problem, how can I remove the cache on linux and automate that action when loading different conda env.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing an strace an spyder shows it was opening things from ~/.local/lib/python3.8.

Deleting this directory (actually renaming it, just in case), fixed the problem...
...if it can help others.

Not sure when python create this lib dir, and how conda is supposed to handle these "caches"

Comment: Pip installs packages in that directory when the `--user` flag is used. Conda users are strongly discouraged from using that flag and, yes, deleting/renaming it is a good idea. Conda cannot ensure well-defined behavior if packages are leaking in user- or system-level installations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be

- You have different version of python installed
- Somehow Conda didn't manage to install them
  In Conda there is a neat way to remove the cache

  usage: conda clean [-h] [-a] [-i] [-p] [-t] [-f]
  [-c TEMPFILES [TEMPFILES ...]] [-d] [--json] [-q] [-v] [-y]

where you could use

```
    -a, --all
Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.

    -i, --index-cache
Remove index cache.
```

Comment: sadly, none of the clean commands helped. 
conda lists only python3.8.8. (Not sure how that relates to python installed by other package managers (e.g. apt), though: I can run python2 and get python2.7...)